# How to extract first letter from each line from a file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

This is my code so far:

```
FOR /f %%G IN (temp.file) DO (
    echo %%G > temp
    first_char.exe temp > letter
    set /p myLetter =<letter
    echo %myLetter%
)
```

`first_char.exe` prints to the stdout the first char from the input file.

It prints:

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

(because I have 6 lines of text in `temp.file`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't see why you need a `first_char` exe file to extract a single char, a simple `var:~0,1` should also work.

Your `ECHO is off.` problem is a problem of the expansion time of `%myLetter%`.
It's expanded when the complete parenthesis block is parsed, at this time `myLetter%` is empty, therefor you got only empty lines.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f %%G IN (temp.file) DO (
    set "var=%%G"
    set "myLetter=!var:~0,1!"
    echo !myLetter!
)
```